# Stereo rendering a sphere with cardboard

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, google-cardboard, 360-degrees

I'm making a 360 media player with Cardboard SDK in android (actually I'm using the new GoogleVR SDK, but it works pretty much alike). To do this I'm following [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=GoogleCardboardPhotoSphere-VR--master/CardboardPhotoSphere/src/main/java/com/cardboard/photosphere/Sphere.java#getFragmentShader-Context-context) code:

Everything works great with a monocular vision and with a stereo one when not distorted (cardboardView.setDistortionCorrectionEnabled(false)). But when I try to use the distortion correction it draws this:

[image]

I've found this in the GVR API:

> If distortion correction is enabled the GL context will be set to draw
>   into a framebuffer backed by a texture at the time of this call, so if
>   an implementor need to change the framebuffer for some rendering stage
>   then the implementor must reset the framebuffer to the one obtained
>   via glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, ...) afterwards.

But I'm not sure if this is related.

This is my onDrawEye code:

```
 /**
 * Draws a frame for an eye.
 *
 * @param eye The eye to render. Includes all required transformations.
 */
@Override
public void onDrawEye(Eye eye) {


    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mView, 0, eye.getEyeView(), 0, mCamera, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mViewProjectionMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mView, 0);

    mSphere.draw(mViewProjectionMatrix);

    checkGLError("onDrawEye");

}
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks so much

(By the way, if I draw a cube instead of a sphere everything works well)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, almost 2 months later I finally solved my problem. If someone wants to know how, it was not a problem of gvr but how I was initializing my scene. Basically i moved every work in the Sphere constructor to the draw method but the shaders initiallization.